# Creating a regex that allows 9 or 10 digits

Tags: regex

I need help with a regex

I need it to match either a 9 or 10 digit value that starts with `50`.

I have:

```
^[ ]*(50)[0-9]{7}[ ]*$
```

which allows 9 digits.

How can I expand this so that it also allows 10 digits?

Comment: Change your {7} to {7,8}

Answer (score 6):

Add the range {7,8}

```
^[ ]*(50)[0-9]{7,8}[ ]*$
```

FYI [this site](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quantifiers) describes the standard quantifiers that you can use in a regular expression:

```
* Match 0 or more times
+ Match 1 or more times
? Match 1 or 0 times
{n} Match exactly n times
{n,} Match at least n times
{n,m} Match at least n but not more than m times
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with following regex:

```
^[ ]*50\d{7,8}[ ]*$
```

Answer (score 2):

This regex will match what you need:

```
^\s*50\d{7,8}\s*$
```

This will match all 9 or 10 digit numbers starting with 50 with an unlimited number of spaces before, or after, them on the line.

If you want to match all 9 or 10 digit numbers starting with 50 regardless of position and number of spaces etc then:

```
50\d{7,8}
```

will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need: `(50)\d{7,8}`